# How to delete imported sql procedures

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have an imported SQL procedure I would like to delete. Its syntax starts with:

```
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE DEFINER=`cloudsqlimport`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `someProc`(IN cui_in CHAR(8), IN kind CHAR(20))
     ...
```

When attempted to delete it with "root" user, using:

```
DROP PROCEDURE someProc
```

I get:

```
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

How can I delete this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the DROP PROCEDURE someProc; must works for this. I have tried at my end, I have created a SP and then I have deleted it using that command as you can see in the below image. So, from where you are trying to perform this task? I would recommend you to use the Cloud Shell since I performed this there with no issue.

[image]

****UPDATED****

It seems like you rae right regarding your comment. When you imported the SP using `cloudsqlimport`@`127.0.0.1` it is not possible to delete it using the command DROP PROCEDURE within MySQL. Nevertheless, as a workaround, you can create a sql file with the following

```
USE `my-database`;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS someProc;

DELIMITER ;
```

Once you have created such a file, you only need to import it to your Cloud SQL database and the SP will be deleted.

As a recommendation I would like to suggest you to do not use `cloudsqlimport`@`127.0.0.1` I think that a best option is to use `root`@`%`

Comment: I think the main issue here is the the SP is not created by "root" user. Because it's imported, it's created by "cloudsqlimport" user

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if now it works for you

Answer (score -1):

DROP PROCEDURE DEFINER.someproc;
syntax :
DROP PROCEDURE .;

Comment: I get "PROCEDURE DEFINER.someproc does not exist"